# XPages and XINC ECL Permission denied

Tags: xpages, managed-bean, xpinc

So I've been a good boy and I've replaced tons of SSJS with a shiny Managed Bean. Now I'm testing in the Notes Client and I'm getting an XPINC Error;

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ECL Permission Denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
ECL Permission Denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
```

The IBM [Developer Wiki](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_in_the_Notes_Client-Security) suggests to set

In the \Data\workspace.config\rcpinstall.properties file, add the following line,

```
com.ibm.xsp.adapter.notescontext.level=FINEST
```

in the file \Data\workspace.config\rcpinstall.properties

But the only reulst I'm getting is

```
NotesContext checkEcl: No permission for (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
```

And here I'm not getting it; I'm the signer of the database, my own entry is allowed to do everything, so why is the ECL striking?

The Managed Bean is not doing too wild things either, it's opening another notes databases, reading a view, making a notesviewnavigator, and storing in memory the view data.

Right now I'm stumped and frustrated about XPinc.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The lazy option is to pry open the Java security settings. The less lazy: post the bean, so the problem can be spotted

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of the problem, the error message was misleading. I had a managed bean that was trying to access another database to which the user had no access. The problem mentioned above with the ECL disappeared after the access to the second database was sorted out.